# Proof of asymptotic stability

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, stability-in-odes

The general solution of the homogeneous equation $Ly = 0$ is given by:

$y(t) = c_1(t)e^{λ_1t} + c_2(t)e^{λ_2t} ... c_m(t)e^{λ_mt}$, where $c_j(t)$ is an arbitrary polynomial of degree $k_j − 1$.

If $r$ is a nonnegative integer and $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$, how can I show that
$\lim_{t\to\infty} |(t^r)(e^{λt})| = 0$ if $\Re(λ) < 0$?

Comment: Is the limit meant to be w.r.t to t?

Comment: @Enforce Yes - thank you for pointing that out. Just edited.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

$$\left|e^{z}\right| = e^{\text{Re}(z)}$$